# how to load images from the Internet for songs in the sd card?

Tags: android

I have a listview list of songs taken from sd card I want to load images from the Internet for the songs in the listview then how?

Comment: when you finish getting images from internet, you just need to place them into your dataset(you pass to your adapter), then notifyDataSetChange()

Answer (score 0):

I think your purpose is to show the album or song cover image for that particular song in the listview, this can be done by directly extracting the embedded picture from the songs itself in the following way-

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource("songPath");
byte [] data = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
if(data != null)
{
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
// Use this bitmap to add to image view 
}
else{
//This means image is not embedded in the audio file
//and pick image form other source
}
```

If you really want to get images from internet for each song, then first you have to find out the list of corresponding image for each song  and then download each songs by this-

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
try {
    java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(src);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
            .openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    return myBitmap;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
}
```

If you are looking for some source from where you can get the image by providing some details about the song, I guess there is no such direct source available.